# How do I have more gold than the max?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Here it shows my max gold is 2500, yet I have over that. How is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you collect gold when you're near max, and the amount collected + current gold is greater than max, then that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Once you reload the game it should fix itself, or it should display "Client and Server are out of sync."

This sometimes happens when the server lags and can't fix it in time. You can also try visiting someone else then coming back.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a glitch or a bug, to fix this just close and open the app and hopefully it will reset.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question is how he has more good than max and my answer is that It is a glitch or bug.

Answer (score -1):

You can hold gold in your mine and the gold in your mine shows up in the top right corner as how much gold you have

Comment: This is incorrect. You can easily test this yourself by collecting gold from a gold mine and watching the amount of gold you have increasing.